This Serverless Function has crashed - Vercel unable to read environment variables
My Remix project works correctly in both development and build mode (running npm run dev and npm run build). But when I upload it to Vercel, along with the environment variables, I get the error: This Serverless Function has crashed.
I therefore ran the command line 'vercel dev', and it gave me this error: 'TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY')'. The environment variables are all stored correctly in the Vercel settings, and I have then imported into the Firebase config file like so:
// firebase/firebase.ts

import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: import.meta.env.VITE_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
};

// Check if a Firebase app has already been initialized
const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
const db = getFirestore(app);
const auth = getAuth(app);

export { app, db, auth };

Is there anything I'm missing? Here is a link to the GitHub repo, though I'm not sure how well it'll replicate without the .env file: https://github.com/alfiemitchell123/personal-finance-app.
Thanks in advance,
Alfie
